# Cast shadow in a specific orthographic area

Tags: three.js

I want to create a `SpotLight` such that the shadow map covers a specific orthographic area, or a `PlaneGeometry`. The default settings however appear to create a shadow area based on the frustrum of the light. Given that the frustrum is rotated and scaled compared to the plane, it is not possible to simply alter that frustrum. I'd have to make it very large to cover the intended area, and then the resolution is low.

Is there some way to create a light for which the shadow is calculated on a specific recipient area (either a plane or an orthographic region)?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a second spotlight which is child of the first spotlight and position set to 0,0,0. And you should set the target to the plane. And onlyShadow set to true.

That way you can have the second spotlight pretending to be the first spotlight but with a detailed shadowmap.

EDIT OLD ANSWER (misinformed):

> It is possible to use a directional light to create an orthograpic
>   shadow.
>
> https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/renderers/plugins/ShadowMapPlugin.js#L169
>
> This directional Light can be set to be onlyshadow.
>
> https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/lights/DirectionalLight.js#L16
>
> The expected frame can be set with the shadowCamera.
>
> https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/lights/DirectionalLight.js#L20-L26
>
> And the angle can be set with setting the position to the calculated
>   normal of the plane.

Comment: The frame is still rotated/scaled based on the directionalight source angle -- it is based on the angle of the directional light, thus won't exactly cover the desired target area.

Comment: Update the answer to be more explicit about the angle

Comment: Yes, I know about the shadowCamera* settings. The problem is the frustrum is still rotated compared to the target area I want. That means I have to greatly increase the size of the shadowCamera to cover the target area, and then the quality is very low (since the map is for the whole enlarged area). Note that I don't want the light to cast a shadow along the normal to the plane, I want it offset on the plane.

Comment: seems like I misunderstood. You should have a second spotlight in the same spot as the first, which only casts a shadow on the plane. The second spotlight can be calculated to just contain the plane. The second spotlight should have onlyShadow = true.